# Can WKWebView persist location services permission?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, geolocation, wkwebview

I'm writing an ios app which is mostly implemented in a web view, and runs inside a native app.

Is there a way to persist the granted permission across web view sessions or must the user grant permission in the web view each time the web view loads within the native app? Asking the user to re-authorize the same website over and over creates a very poor user experience.

I have read the documentation for UIWebView and WKWebView, but haven't found any mention there, nor any mention on stackoverflow to date, so perhaps I'm asking the community to help me prove a negative here :) Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on that problem ? I'm facing the same issue, I don't how Safari and Chrome manage that..

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43907448/2432781