# Multiple location permission issue in WKWebView iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my application, I have simply loaded one URL in WKWebView but it is asking me location permission twice, One is from application and one is from WKWebview(i.e. Browser)

I only want one location permission, I have already tried "evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)"  But it's not working for iOS 14.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent WKWebView to repeatedly ask for permission to access location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but no luck with above answer