# How to avoid InAppWebView to twice ask for permission to access location?

Tags: flutter, webview, permissions, local

I did not find an answer to the question of how to do this in flutter.
The problem is the following:
when requesting permissions for geolocation, first the first window pops up directly for the application itself, then the second one for the WebView.

So the request for the WebView looks just disgusting, all because I'm running the **WebView
locally**(without a local server).

I found a similar article but it is directly for Swift, I could not figure out how to adapt it for Flutter: [How to prevent WKWebView to repeatedly ask for permission to access location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665367/how-to-prevent-wkwebview-to-repeatedly-ask-for-permission-to-access-location)

Actually my question is:
**How can I get rid of that second request?** Because it sure isn't great UX...

[first nice request for app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOjNq.png)

[second ugly request for webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLqSt.png)