Avoid double location permission pop up in MAUI Webview for iOS
So I want to implement a MAUI app which loads a Webview. The Webview needs access to the gps location of the device. I added the necessary permissions in the Info.plist which worked. But now I get two permission pop ups when using the app. The permission which is added in the Info.plist and than the permission from the WebView which has the message: "This website will use your precise location because "AppName" currently has access to your precise location".
I had a similar error with the camera permissions but that problem got solved with implementing a custom WebViewDelegate and granting all incoming requests. Is there a solution like this for the location permissions of the WebView?

Please check this hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907448/833395

That solution is for swift. But I don't know how to do that in Maui.

Is this help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android
